# Semaphores in c linux with Client/server

Tags: c, linux, client-server, semaphore

I need some help.

I want to create 2 semaphores:
1st semaphore. for a client to lock the semaphore when it finished writing to shared memory - and only the server will be able to read from the shared memory.
2nd semaphore. after the server red from the shared memory the server will open the semaphore for writing.

I want to client to write to Shared memory, and afterwards only the server can work(read the shared memory). Then (after the server red the data) some client can write to the shared memory. and so on...

does anyone has an idea how to do that?

tnx.

Comment: "Semaphore" is not a question. Semaphore is a solution. Please specify what you are actually trying to achieve. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to client to write to Shared memory, and afterwards only the server can work(read the shared memory). Then (after the server red the data) some client can write to the shared memory. and so on...

Comment: Do you want only one client to be able to write to the buffer at a time?

Comment: yes, one client at a time.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem?  You have two semaphores.  Use one 'access' unit, and pass it around the semaphores.

Comment: What does it mean? one access unit?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is two semaphores controlling access. One semaphore sets whether a client is allowed to write to the buffer, and another whether the server is allowed to read from it.

Each client tries to acquire the buffer write semaphore. When it succeeds, it writes its data, and then increments the read semaphore.

The server, in a loop, acquires the read semaphore, processes the data, and then increments the write semaphore.

This solution suffers from a severe performance problem, however. All of your tasks are, effectively, completely serialized. No client can post jobs while the server is processing these jobs. No two clients can prepare jobs at the same time. Despite your multi-threaded design, you are only effectively utilizing one core here.

A better solution would be to have two buffers, and have the server process one job while a client prepares the next one. The synchronizations become more complex here, as you need to make sure we pick the correct buffer each time.